# Laravel Relations has problem with retrieve data

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have BelnogstoMany relation in my model which I defined like this

```
class MailUsers extends Model
{
      public function group ()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Group', 'user_groups','user_id','group_id');
        }

}
```

and in the other model, I defined the relationship like this

```
class Group extends Model
{  
 public function customer ()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\MailUsers', 'user_groups','group_id','user_id');
    }

}
```

when I save data it saves the relation in the user_groups table without problem, and I have this data in it

select * from user_groups;

```
+----+---------+----------+
| id | user_id | group_id |
+----+---------+----------+
|  1 |       5 |        1 |
|  2 |      16 |        1 |
+----+---------+----------+
```

my problem is when I am trying to retrieve the data with relation it returns null even it has a relation in the table

```
 $data=MailUsers::with(['group'])->get();
```

it keeps returning null in the group even the records has relation as  I show above

if I try to print the SQL statements  with toSql Function it returns this without any join

```
select * from mail_users;
```

I have no idea why that is happening  , I was working with relation in laravel , and this is the first time  that  I have just like this problem

Answer (score 0):

Try getting relationship without putting them in `[]`

```php
$data = MailUsers::with('group')->get();
```

Then, you can get the group as below

```php
$data->pluck('group');
```

Comment: it is same , the  query return null in the group